# PySpark LDA Model Dense Vector from RDD

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I set up my data to feed into the Apache Spark LDA model. The one hangup I'm having is converting the list to a Dense Vector because I have some alphanumeric values in my RDD. The error I receive when trying to run the example code is around converting a string to float.

I understand this error knowing what I know about a dense vector and a float, but there has to be a way to load these string values into an LDA model since this is a topic model.

I should have prefaced this by stating I'm new to Python and Spark so I apologize if I'm misinterpreting something. I'll add my code below. Thank you in advance!

**Example**

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda

**Code:**

```python
>>> rdd = rdd5.take(3)
[[u'11394071', u'11052103', u'11052101'], [u'11847272', u'11847272', 
u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', 
u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'999999', u'11847272', 
u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', 
u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272', u'11847272'], [u'af1lowprm1704', 
u'af1lowprm1704', u'af1lowprm1704', u'af1lowprm1704', u'af1lowprm1704', 
u'am1prm17', u'am1prm17', u'af1highprm1704', u'af1highprm1704']]

>>> parsedData = rdd.map(lambda line: Vectors.dense([float(x) for x in 
line]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: af1lowprm1704
```

**Next Steps in Code Once Fixed:**

```python
# Index Document with Unique ID's
corpus = parsedData.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: [x[1], x[0]]).cache()

# Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
ldaModel = LDA.train(corpus, k=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indeed misinterpreting the example: the file `sample_lda_data.txt` does not contain text ([check it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_lda_data.txt)), but word count vectors that have already been extracted from a corpus. This is indicated in the text preceding the example:

> In the following example, we load word count vectors representing a corpus of documents.

So, you need to get these word count vectors first from your own corpus, before proceeding as you try.

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut ! I need to read more about the LDA model. My understanding was I would feed in 'documents' and based on the counts of text in relation to each other it would derive topic probabilities.